# Most Streamlined Way to use Basic Authentication with Web Application and CDN

Tags: html, cdn, basic-authentication

I have a site whose pre-production environments use HTTP basic authentication to prevent unauthorized access. Recently, we've added a CDN (AWS Cloudfront) and we intend to use basic authentication (FWIW, using Lambda@Edge) for those pre-production CDN environments, as well.

While we've already implemented basic authentication on the web application (we're able to access the site after authentication), and have rudimentarily implemented basic authentication on the CDN (we're able to, say, access an image directly, after authentication), we're having trouble combining the two.

The web application includes images in the normal ways (e.g., via HTML and CSS includes). For instance, my site, https://www.example.com, has the following in its HTML:

```html
<img src="https://cdn-files.example.com/foob.png" />
```

Using Chrome, when hitting the web application, I get a double-challenge (one for the app's domain and one for the CDN, each in turn), and the image loads.

Using Firefox, I get a single challenge, and the page loads, but the image fails to load (that request's response is 401).

Question 1: (Most streamlined option.) Is it possible, through the right configuration settings, to get the browser to pass through the credentials from the app's domain to the CDN domain? If so, what configurations are needed?

If not:

Question 2: (Less streamlined: Double-challenge.) What's the right combination of configurations (presumably, headers, etc.) to get the images, etc., to load on the web app?

---

I would prefer not to embed the credentials in the URLs, if at all possible.

Comment: You can include them in the URL. See https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Comment: Thanks, @CharlieSchliesser, I'd prefer not to add the credentials that way (just added that stipulation), and I _think_ there's a way to do it without, but I guess we'll see.

Comment: I think there's a solution using maybe the `crossorigin` attribute (`<img src="https://cdn-files.example.com/foob.png" crossorigin="use-credentials" />`) along with a handful of specific headers on the CDN side, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Try the `crossorigin` attribute and let us know! The docs suggest that works for `script`, `img`, and other resource tags and includes cookies and HTTP authentication. If not, you could try triggering 1 request to `cdn-files.example.com` that includes credentials, letting it finish, and *then* loading your other resources.

Comment: It's not an answer, but if you used HTTPS, would it matter if the credentials were in in the URL ?